# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SVM_LINEAR'

Tags: python, opencv, svm

I have installed open cv 3.0 then i installed libsvm.Then i addded that to my pycharm packages.But still when typing this code

```
svm_params = dict( kernel_type = cv2.SVM_LINEAR,
                svm_type = cv2.SVM_C_SVC,
                C=2.67, gamma=5.383 )
```

it shows this error

```
svm_params = dict( kernel_type = cv2.SVM_LINEAR,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SVM_LINEAR'
```

i tried import libsvm but it didn't work.please help.
Is opencv 3.0 is ok should i go back to 2.4?

Comment: You might be use different version, please check `opencv` 3.0 code, this variable might be not exist in that. You have to use `cv2.ml.SVM_LINEAR`

Comment: @Lafada Thank you very much it worked.opencv 3.0 lot of changes.very confusing.Most examples in internet are opencv 2.4.x.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are accessing `SVM_LINEAR` with `cv2`, but `SVM_LINEAR` is attribute of `ml`.

You have to access `SVM_LINEAR` as `cv2.ml.SVM_LINEAR`