# I got Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int' while performing svm.predict() in opencv3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to classify images using sift feature descriptors with the help of 
opencv3 and python3.
My code is like this

```
#some previous lines of code above...

import cv2.ml
print("svm items", len(train_desc), len(train_desc[0]))
count=0
svm = cv.ml.SVM_create()
svm.setType(cv2.ml.SVM_C_SVC)
svm.setKernel(cv2.ml.SVM_LINEAR)
svm.setTermCriteria((cv.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 100, 1.e-06))
svm.train(np.array(train_desc), cv.ml.ROW_SAMPLE ,np.array(train_labels))
i=0
j=0

confusion = np.zeros((40,40))
def classify(pth):
  feature = feature_extract(pth)
  p = svm.predict(feature)
  confusion[train_labels[count]-1,p-1] = confusion[train_labels[count]-1,p-1] +1

for p in training_paths:
  classify(p)
  count+=1
```

Then I got this error

```
    TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-511fc16d25b1> in <module>()
      1 for p in training_paths:
----> 2     classify(p)
      3     count+=1
<ipython-input-77-e2187ad1b52e> in classify(pth)
      3     feature = feature_extract(pth)
      4     p = svm.predict(feature)
----> 5     confusion[train_labels[count]-1,p-1] = confusion[train_labels[count]-1,p-1] +1

 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

I was trying to implement the code from [this github account](https://github.com/briansrls/SIFTBOW/blob/master/SIFTBOW.py)

Comment: Please edit and mention which line raises that error.

Comment: Well, what's `p`? Print it out. (the other possibility is `train_labels[count]`, since those are the two places you subtract and integer)

Comment: I referred the main code from [https://github.com/briansrls/SIFTBOW/blob/master/SIFTBOW.py](https://github.com/briansrls/SIFTBOW/blob/master/SIFTBOW.py)

Comment: And that was running on cv2.4. And I am using cv3, so svm() instace claaling had a problem so I   referred from this stackoverflow thread [creating svm with OpenCV-3.0.1 / python 2.7
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038861/creating-svm-with-opencv-3-0-1-python-2-7)

Comment: p is a tupple in the classify() function